# Android - Incoming call notification not vibrating and ringtone not playing

Tags: android, audio, notifications, call, vibration

I'm trying to show a notification when receiving push notification from firebase.

```
private fun showIncomingCallNotification(title: String?, content: String?){

    val fullScreenIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 5678,
        fullScreenIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, INCOMING_CALL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(content)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true)
        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
        .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM))
        .setOngoing(true)
        .build()

    startForeground(1010, notification)
}


private fun createIncomingCallNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val mChannel = NotificationChannel(INCOMING_CALL_ID, INCOMING_CALL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        mChannel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM), null)
        mChannel.enableVibration(true)

        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
    }
}
```

Although the notification shows, the sound is the default notification sound and it does not vibrate. I ensured I'm using the vibrate permissions too.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello brother ? Have your found the solution for this. I am stuck in this too. My phone is not vibrating but the ringer is working